# Group rows where row in variable x equals row in vari

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I'm working with large administrative datasets, which the patients are linked to an index number using personal identifiers. There are cases where the personal identifiers are matched to two indexes, but with varying degrees of confidence. I have a dataset of over 1 millions Index numbers but I've created a small example data.

```
data.frame(Index = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
            Duplicate = c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1), 
            Duplicate_with = c(NA, 10, NA, 9, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 2),
            Grade = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B")) -> data
```

'Index' is the Index number of the patient, 'Duplicate' highlights if the Index is a duplicate (0=No; 1=Yes), 'Duplicate_with' gives the Index for which it was a duplicate to, and 'Grade' is the confidence of a correct match using the personal identifiers.

I would like to group together the rows where Index in row x equals Duplicate_with in row y to end up with

```
     Index Duplicate Duplicate_with Grade Group
1      1         0             NA     A     1
2      2         1             10     A     2
3      3         0             NA     A     3
4      4         1              9     B     4
5      5         0             NA     A     5
6      6         0             NA     A     6
7      7         0             NA     A     7
8      8         0             NA     A     8
9      9         1              4     C     4
10     10        1              2     B     2
```

So for example, if Index==1, search in Duplicate_with for 1, and then group. If Index==2, then search in Duplicate_with for 2, and then group.

Could anyone please give me some advice on coding this and I've ran out of ideas?

My apologies if my question is not clear, or could be improved, this is my first time posting so I will also take any tips on improving the question.

Answer (score 2):

Is group equal to the earliest Index of the patient or their match?
If these are 1:1 relationships, this should suffice:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(group = pmin(Index, Duplicate_with, na.rm = TRUE))

   Index Duplicate Duplicate_with Grade group
1      1         0             NA     A     1
2      2         1             10     A     2
3      3         0             NA     A     3
4      4         1              9     B     4
5      5         0             NA     A     5
6      6         0             NA     A     6
7      7         0             NA     A     7
8      8         0             NA     A     8
9      9         1              4     C     4
10    10         1              2     B     2
```

If it's possible that a patient X could match patient Y, who could match patient Z, then you may need to look into network analysis e.g. with `igraph` to identify groups with more than 2 patients.

Comment: The fact that group was the same as the earliest index was by coincidence (or bad design of example), however there would be no issue that the group was as such, I just need something so I could then use distinct() to get the highest graded match. Yes it is a 1:1 match. Unfortunately my servers have crashed, and probably won't be fixed until the morning (posting from Scotland) so I will attempt on my actual data then. However, thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you are achieving and how you are making the rules to determine what is assigned into group.
But given your input you can achieve your output with a couple of `ifelse` statements.

```
data.frame(Index = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
           Duplicate = c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1), 
           Duplicate_with = c(NA, 10, NA, 9, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 2),
           Grade = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B")) -> dat


data$group <- ifelse(is.na(data$Duplicate_with), data$Index,
ifelse(data$Duplicate_with<data$Index, data$Duplicate_with,rownames(data)))
```

Again without knowing the relationship and rules it is hard to know what to code. I suspect that the `ifelse` statements will break with real word IDs (unless the are completely numeric).

Comment: The idea is to be able to group together the duplicate Index numbers so I can then easily retain the duplicate with the highest grade. The Index in the actual data can be made numeric, so should be ok there. There is a 1:1 relationship, so each Index which has been marked as a duplicate with link to one other Index. Unfortunately my servers have crashed, and probably won't be fixed until the morning (posting from Scotland) so I will attempt on my actual data then. However, thank you for your advice.